# RAM requirements for hadoop production cluster

Tags: hadoop

iam using hadoop apache 2.7.1 on centos 7

with HA Cluster that consists of 2 name nodes and 8 datanodes 
(both name nodes are journal nodes too + 3 data nodes as journal nodes )

with replication factor=3 and  blocksize = 1mb

my inserted files will not exceed 1 mb in size

if iam planning to insert about 10000000 records

what are suitable ram capacity required for theses nodes?

i have read links which refer that datanode should have more memory than name node becuase of map reduce ,is that true ?what idf we don't have map reduce yet

Comment: What do you mean you don't have MapReduce? That's part of core Hadoop.

Comment: Anyway, this is a site for programming questions, not hardware sizing. Try https://serverfault.com

Comment: *my inserted files will not exceed 1 mb*...  Oh, that's very bad. You do not need Hadoop... You are wasting more memory keeping references to the actual files. You should really attempt to make archive files of your records to correctly use HDFS as it was designed

Comment: ok  i know that map reduce is the core of hadoop ,but may be i don't have these needs now

Comment: Then what's the point? Just storing files? Use NFS or some other NAS system